# Isomorphisms Between Multiplicative and Additive Modulo Groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, abelian-groups

While working with the fundamental theorem of Abelian groups, I noticed something and would like to confirm my assumption.

$$(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^* \cong  \mathbb{Z}/φ(n)\mathbb{Z} $$

Is the above true? If so why exactly?

Comment: it's true for some $n$, but not all; for example, it's not true for $n=8$

Comment: yes, you are right! thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your statement is true for some $n$, but not for all $n$.  For example, it's not true for $n=8$.

---

Addendum:  I recommend this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) article, which states that

the group $ (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is cyclic if and only if $n$ is $ 1, 2, 4,$ $p^k$ or $2p^k$,

where $ p$ is an odd prime and $k > 0$.

Comment: is it ture when n is prime perhaps?

Comment: Right there in the answer: an odd prime has cyclic group of units since it is an integer of the form $p^k$ with $k=1$.